# Unable To Create Signed APK in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, android-studio-3.0

after i clicked on generate signed apk It Shows "APK Generated Successfully" but there is no apk in the folder.
I tried Clean,Rebuild,Invalidate Cache/Restart but after all that Android Studio Not generating apk but  shows "apk generated success fully"

Comment: In which folder you are checking ?

Comment: I checked {MyAppFolder}/app/release - and i founded the file,  but when i click generate signed apk it asks for the location where the apk will be generated, but  the apk still get created on "app/release" folder.                            Do I have to Clean and  Rebuild   every time before generating signed apk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android Studio 3.0 update, the apk generated will be in :

```
{project}/app/release/app-release.apk
```

The new structure is :

```
{APK Destination Folder} \ {flavor} \ {variant} \ {apkname}.apk
```

Comment: I found it. Its there but when i delete and Generate Signed APK its not creating new apk. Why is that?

Comment: Did you refresh ? it will be there

Comment: I did, but its like i have to refresh at least 4 times.

Comment: There is a problem with you OS, not Android Studio. you can check existing via CMD after generation @SarathSVS